# Jenkins Issue: local class incompatible by comparing serialVersionUID

Tags: java, maven, deployment, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm having a problem with Jenkins 1.520 and a strange exception about serialization IDs.

I have a maven project in Jenkins that first check out code from subversion, then runs a 'mvn clean install' and finally deploys the generated war to another preproduction server.

First time I run this project everything was ok, but after first execution I'm suffering this exception:

```
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.InvalidClassException: hudson.maven.PlexusModuleContributor$1; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -647770169695782116, local class serialVersionUID = 1
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:604)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1601)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1514)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1750)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.deserialize(UserRequest.java:182)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:98)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Finished: FAILURE
```

As you can see, the point is "local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -647770169695782116, local class serialVersionUID = 1". Conflict of different serialVersionUID when is expected to be the same.

I've been reading about this issue in jenkins jira and here, but no one has a real solution for this. Only someone talks about downgrading version of jenkins.

I thought maybe it was a conflict of java versions between the version specified in pom.xml and the version of jenkins server, but both use jdk 1.7. Maybe a jenkins bug then?

Any suggestion?

Thank you!

**SOLUTION**: Finally downgrading version from 1.520 to 1.509.2 (Long Term Support) works for us.

Comment: Is your Jenkins a standalone install or do you have some slaves ?

Comment: The person who installed it told me that it's a standalone install (includes tomcat) in Red Hat Linux, using command "yum install Jenkins"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this seems to be a known problem : see https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18533

If don't need the latest versions of Jenkins, I would suggest to switch to the [LTS (Long Term Support)](http://jenkins-ci.org/changelog-stable) version of Jenkins. Theses versions ensure stability needed for production server, when you don't have time (or envy) to track bugs in latest releases.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume, I saw that ticket a couple hours ago, and I was trying to find and alternative to switch version, but maybe it's the only option by now.. I will wait a bit maybe someone has a trick ;)